# iOS MVVM: Is Delegation Pattern a Requirement?

Tags: ios, mvvm, delegates, key-value-observing, delegation

First of, researching MVVM for iOS is a headache as there are multiple varying implementations floating around online. So far I found 3 categories of MVVM:

1. MVVM that uses Delegation / Protocols to update the ViewController / View
2. MVVM with KVO binding like ReactiveCocoa
3. MVVM as a simple helper / wrapper class for the model (no protocols, no KVO)

Is Delegation Pattern or KVO a requirement for implementing MVVM in iOS?

I've seen a number of MVVM examples online that do not make use of Protocols / Delegation, and instead just use MVVM as a helper class to encapsulate the Model and provide state to the ViewController.

Is that still considered MVVM?

Comment: MVVM is definitely not what Apple had in mind when they created Cocoa Touch. There's a reason Apple dox specifically teach MVC. In iOS, what problem does MVVM solve? First answer is always a big view controller. But why is that a problem? It's not. Trimming down one "big" object by doubling the number of objects and creating an unearthly amount of observers and view extensions is not a solution. MVVM is a memory hog and memory is the most valuable resource in application development. If Apple wanted developers to 2-way bind everything, Swift would at least have it as a native feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I totally agree with you, it's really a painful job to get correct understanding about MVVM on internet as everyone has their own implementation, I had the same situation as yours.

It does not really matter which approach are you following to implement MVVM as long as you are not violating below rules:

**View:**

1. Owns ModelView
2. Manages view cycle.
3. Handel user interaction and pass actions to ModelView.

**ModelView:**

1. It owns Model
2. Perform all business operations.
3. It notifies to View on updates

**Model:**

1. It notifies to ModelView on updates.

So as per the rules above either you can go with 1st or 2nd point as 3rd is not applicable here because without binding or notifying you cannot achieve MVVM.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

It my opinion of MVVM.

MVVM or MV-whatever is just a architecture try to separate the **view** and **logic**. It have some benefits like enhance your code testability and follow SRP let your debug much easier... etc.

Another key point, MVVM communicate between `View-Model` and `View` use `data binding`, when user update the value from UI, and the value directly update to `View-Model`.

As you say, there have several choice to implement MVVM. But if you choice the option 3, how to binding the value from `View-Model` to `View` and `Model` to `View-Model`?

If using KVO `View` can observed `View-Model`'s 
 propertys but `View-Model` didn't need to know anything about `View`.

If using delegate pattern, `View-Model` just need to implement what `View` needed and nothing more need to know about `View`.

Using KVO or delegate pattern is just try to decoupling between `View-Model` and `View`, and `data binding` between them.

So I think the option 3 didn't considered MVVM. Maybe it still strong coupling between `View` and `View-Model`.